# How to add new value which is unrelated to list<T>

Tags: c#, list, generics, arraylist, collections

`List<Student>` contain id and name.
`List<Studentdetails>` contain id and address , Student class id is mapped to Studentdetails.

My service derived an interface which will return only `List<Student>` . But I also need to bind the Address data from `Studentdetails` in the User interface.

How can I achieve this logic, is there any way that I can override and add the address in `List<Student>` list ?

Comment: If `student` only has properties `id` and `name` you will need to add an `address` property and update this based on your `List<StudentDetails>`

Comment: It is a database model class i cant update the property. Without adding the address property, is there any other possibilities to get the data? .

Comment: Is the model being used for Entity Framework code first or something similar? You could add an address field and use the data annotation [NotMapped] so that the database is not affected and then just added the address in your service.

Comment: @stefanedwinPrasanth Are you using Entity Framework? If so, you can use a partial class of `Student` to add an `Address` property. Otherwise you could always define a new class with your three properties

Comment: @ivcubr Yes i am using entity framework.

Comment: "Student class id is mapped to `Studentdetails`". What does this mean? Does this mean that for a `Student` with the `id` of 1, I can find that `Student`'s address in the `Studentdetails` instance with an `id` of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a partial class to extend the auto-generated class from Entity Framework.

The auto-generated class from Entity Framework most likely looks like this (you didn't post so I am guessing):

```
public partial class Student {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In a separate file, add an `Address` property like shown below:

```
public partial class Student {
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use the `address` property on your `Student` class:

```
Student s1 = new Student {
    Id = 1,
    Name = "test",
    Address = "test"
};
```

Note that the answer from @Will will work but if you regenerate your model from the database this will be lost and you will have to manually re-add it. This solution will not be affect by subsequent database updates.

Comment: Will EF pick this up as a change and require a migration, thus adding the address field to the student table?

Comment: @Will not to my knowledge. EF will not know about the new property, but in the OP data service he can return `List<Student>` and have the address property

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your student class (Assuming address is a string if its individual properties just replicate this format for each)

```
    [NotMapped]
    public string Address { get; set; }
```

Then populate each student in the list with their address from the other table in your service. Return your student class as normal and you'll have the address. Using NotMapped will mean it's ignored by Entity Framework so this won't affect your database model.

If you can modify your interface a better solution would be to create a composite model that contains both the Student model and the Address model, you could then return a list of this without cluttering your student class.